# Não consigo desenhar um polygon no Google Maps

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, google-maps

Estou tentando fazer um quadrado com as coordenadas, mas não aparece. Não tem nenhum erro no navegador, o mapa é criado normalmente, somente o quadrado não aparece:

```
var map;

function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-21.723254, -49.356317);

    var options = {
        zoom:30,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var princiCoords = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(-21.724394, -49.356391),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-21.724172, -49.356479),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-21.724044, -49.356040),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-21.724257, -49.355960)
    ];

    var princiPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        // Coordenadas do seu objeto
        paths: princiCoords,
        // Cor do da linha
        strokeColor: '#E12D93',
        // Opacidade da linha
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        // Espessura da linha
        strokeWeight: 4,
        // Cor de preenchimento do objeto
        fillColor: '#942E7C',
        // Opacidade do preenchimento
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });

    princiPolygon.setMap(map);
}

initialize();
```

Comment: Olá **Hugo**, poderia [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/338452/edit) sua pergunta e descrever seu problema?

Comment: No comando para carregar o script da API do Google Maps você incluiu o parâmetro `libraries=geometry`, para incluir essas funções de geometria?

Comment: Não, tem q ser depois da Key ?